# Trying to output an isosceles triangle. I keep getting a right triangle

Tags: c#, loops

```
using System;


namespace Shapes
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Character: ");
            string symbol = (Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Peak of Triangle: ");
            int peak = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());


            int i = 0;
            while (i <= peak) // spaces for triangle
            {

                Console.WriteLine(" ");



                int z = 1;

                while (z <= i) // Symbols for triangle
                {
                    Console.Write(symbol);

                    z++;

                }


                i++;
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Output: should start at one (*) then increase until the peak is met. Then should decrease back down to one of whatever input.

The output I am getting is not decreasing it stops at the peak input

Comment: output should be: 
*
**
***
**
*

Output at the moment
*
**
***

Comment: When you step through this code in a debugger, where does the runtime behavior differ from what you expect?  What are the runtime values when that happens?

Comment: your loop only goes from 0 to peak -and stops - which is what you are seeing. You then need another loop to go back down to 0.

Comment: In which loop would i go back to 0 in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to reverse the counter `i` to count back to 0.

```
Console.WriteLine("Character: ");
string symbol = (Console.ReadLine());
Console.WriteLine("Peak of Triangle: ");
int peak = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine()); // spaces for triangle
int i = 0;
int n = 1;
while (i != -1) // do it until i is negative
{
    Console.WriteLine(" ");

    int z = 1;

    while (z <= i) // Symbols for triangle
    {
        Console.Write(symbol);
        z++;
    }

    i += n; // increments when n = 1. decrements when n = -1

    if (i >= peak) // reverse counter when it reaches peak
    {
        n = -1; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! The comments really helped explain each step.

Comment: @ADB glad it helped. i edited the code. it works and its simpler now. (removed `i -= 2` and instead changed `i > peak` to `i >= peak`)